# Php, загрузка файла одного типа pdf, как сделать проверку, чтобы посторонние файлы нельзя было загружать?

Tags: php

Сделал загрузку `pdf` файла на сервер, теперь думаю как добавить проверку уже в мой метод `php`.
Чтоб можно было загружать только `pdf`.

```
<input type="file" name="pdffile" accept="application/pdf">
```

Функция загрузки и генерации имени:

```
if (isset($_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name']) && ($_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name'])) {
        $orderpdf = ORM::factory('Order', $id);
        if ($orderpdf->loaded()) {
          if ($orderpdf->pdffile != '') {
            @unlink('media/uploads/pdf/' . $orderpdf->pdffile);
          }
        }

        $symbols = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

        $filename = '';
        for ($i = 0;
          $i < 5;
          $i++
        ) {
          $filename .= rand(1, strlen($symbols));
        }
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['pdffile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = 'karta-dk-' . $filename . '.' . $ext;
        $a = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name'], 'media/uploads/pdf/' . $filename);
        $data['pdffile'] = $filename;
      }
```

Comment: я вам предлагаю в `pathinfo` брать не только `PATHINFO_EXTENSION`, но и mime-типа воспользовавшись функцией `mime_content_type`. Соответственно проверять расширение файла и mime-тип на допустимые.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // возвращает mime-тип
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);
if ($mime_type === 'application/pdf') {...}
```

или так

```
<?php
$mime_type = mime_content_type($filename);
if ($mime_type === 'application/pdf') {...}
```

[Документация вариант 1](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.finfo-file.php)
[Документация вариант 2](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: Понял, проверка на расширение файла, так, а в мой код как внедрить.

Comment: не на расширение, а на mime-тип. Но Вы должны понимать, что это никак не гарантирует, что файл именно PDF, что не содержит эксплойтов и других зловредных иньекций. Да, собственно, Вы по сути никак не проверите это (даже если сделать проверку на все известные, то новые найдутся)

Comment: так и как быть, что-то же есть надежное. то что можно внедрить в код.

Answer (score 1):

У PDF файлов есть заголовок, `%PDF-1.4` где `1.4` версия. Прочитав первых 4 байта можно узнать что это `%PDF` или нет.

```php
function isPDF($filename)
{
    $f = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($f === false) return false;
    $header = fread($f, 5);
    fclose($f);
    return $header === '%PDF-';
}
```

Comment: На сколько это надежно, так и в php можно же запихать что-то.

Comment: Ты конечно можешь посмотреть в сторону FPDI `https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about`  она вроде как умеет читать/писать PDF. И проверять реально ли это PDF файл. Но вообще даже в тело 100% валидного PDF можно запихнуть злосчастные `<?php echo file_get_content('/etc/shadow'); ?>`. Я думаю что единственное спасение это не записывать в корень сайта, и отдавать файл своим обработчиком.

Comment: Если совсем нету никакого спасения и тебе точно 100% надо хранить в корне, то ты можешь сжать полученный файл в `gz` и хранить в корне как gz архив, в ответе HTTP надо указать что файлы *.pdf у тебя gz архивированные.